# chrome.storage.sync undefined?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm trying to use chrome storage in an extension, via a content_script, but I keep failing on

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

This is my code:

```js
testChromeStorage();

function testChromeStorage() {  
    console.log("Saving");
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
        message('Settings saved');
    });
    chrome.storage.sync.get("value", function (retVal) {
            console.log("Got it? " + retVal.value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you request the "storage" permission in your manifest file?

Comment: "storage" permission in manifest.json solved my problem.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You have to add the "storage" permission in your manifest.json file, i.e.:

```json
//...
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
//...
```

For more information, see: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Thanks, this is the actual correct answer I would believe .. No need for messaging

Comment: google ALWAYS does that...makes a lot useless help pages...why would'nt they menthion about storage permission here? :https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options

Comment: True, it would be helpful on that page. I just sent them the suggestion as feedback by clicking on the "Report a bug" link on the bottom of the page.

Comment: I will note though, that although the `options` extension and the `storage` extension are often used together, they can actually be used independently from one another. And this requirement is mentioned in the link I posted in the answer. So I wouldn't be surprised if they decide not to add it to the page for the `options` extension.

Comment: How to specify "unlimitedStorage" permission instead  of just "storage"?

Comment: @Chetan Just substitute `"unlimitedStorage"` in place of the `"storage"` permission. But there are a couple limitations with this (taken from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions): "This permission applies only to Web SQL Database and application cache... Also, it doesn't currently work with wildcard subdomains such as `http://*.example.com`."

Comment: I already tried with substitution with "unlimitedStorage" and then i get error  "cannot read property 'sync' of undefined ". i am using chrome.storage.sync to set values. The moment i switch back to storage , then i don't get the error

Comment: That's because you are still using `chrome.storage`, which is no longer in your permissions (and therefore undefined). As I mention in my previous comment, if you want to use `unlimitedStorage`, you will have to use either a Web SQL Database (which is deprecated by the way) or application cache.

Comment: @ProstoTrader 7 years later and it's still not there.

Answer (score 15):

**RELOAD THE EXTENSION**

I had the "permissions" key added in my `manifest` file but still I struggled to get this fixed.

After adding the permission:-

```
"permissions": [
    "storage"
 ]
```

Goto your extension using: chrome://extensions/ & click the Reload button:-

[image]

Comment: Key here ... RELOAD THE EXTENSION

Answer (score 3):

If someone was facing this issue on Firefox, please note, that it is not supported yet:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage#Chrome_incompatibilities

For my purposes it was sufficient to replace `chrome.storage.sync` by `chrome.storage.local`.

Regarding the Firefox implementation state it might be worth to look also here from time to time:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs#storage

Answer (score 1):

**RESTART THE DEV SERVER**

Despite adding the permission and reloading the extension, I sync was still undefined.

Turned out I needed to restart the dev server for the new manifest to picked up.
Which makes sense since this file was not being watched.
Doh!

Answer (score -1):

See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html:

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> *Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)*

(emphasis added)

Comment: However, that page hasn't been updated for a long time. `chrome.runtime` is also available and `chrome.storage` will be available when the "storage" permission is declared.