# How to use chrome.storage extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

My extension popup page gets data from a message from a sand-boxed page & scripts. I need to store this inside the chrome.storage, preferably using the storage.sync method. I'm getting this error:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined*

I already added the permissions for storage inside my manifest.json.

... "permissions": ["storage"], ...
[chrome.storage.sync undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998123/chrome-storage-sync-undefined)

Google alsostates that no backgroud script is needed:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Quoting: *Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.*

What am I overlooking? Thanks in advance!

```
function receiveMessage(event) {
        var data = event.data;
        saveToStorage(data);
    };

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function saveToStorage(data)
{
    if (!data) {
        console.log('Error: No value specified. Nothing saved to storage.');
        return;
    }

    chrome.storage.sync.set({'data': data}, function() {
        console.log('Data saved to storage.');
    });
};
```

Comment: Did you reload your extension after adding the new permission?

Comment: Your code is correct and you should be able to use it. Though with `sync` storage, I would recommend checking `chrome.runtime.lastError` because of the quotas.

Comment: Also, see if you reloaded the extension **and** the page that contains your content script.

Comment: Reloaded everything and it works now. Sometimes it's as easy as that, and i'm as stupid as that :)

Comment: I hate the same issue, and I did reload everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to always reload your extension before testing something new. I never reloaded it before because it wasn't necessary, well until now :)
Also *chrome.runtime.lastError* comes in very handy!