# Chrome storage API not working with content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm using chrome storage API to save data that needs to be accessed on content script page. When I load data in extension settings page like this

```
document.write("chrome.storage.sync.get(\"password\", function(items) {\n");
document.write("var true_password = items.password;\n");
document.write("});\n");
```

it works, but the same code doesn't work with content script...

I'm getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Any idea why?

---

**EDIT**

```
manifest.json
{
"name":"app",
"description":"app...",
"version":"0.1",
"manifest_version":2,
"options_page": "options.html",
"permissions": [ "storage" ],

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.my_page.com/*"],
      "js": ["lock.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998123/chrome-storage-sync-undefined

Comment: I have `"permissions": [ "storage" ]` in my manifest

Comment: Is the code actually in your `lock.js`, or are you trying it from the console?

Comment: And you reloaded both the extension _and the page you're working with_ after adding the permission?

Comment: I added permission 1h ago

Comment: So? Did you reload the extension, then the page to refresh the script? Also, double-check your code for typos. This would appear if you misspelled `storage`.

Comment: Yes, I reloaded the extension, and there are no typos because the same code works in setting.html/.js

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. This should be working normally.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm writing the code with `document.write("chrome.storage.sync.get(\"password\", function(items) {\n");` in lock.js

Comment: _Of course_, since that code leaves the content script context and executes in the page context, which does not have access to the API. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Then we found the problem, tnx! :)

Comment: Maybe, but that makes your question unhelpful. You should edit to include that relevant information.

Comment: There's still the question of why are you using `document.write`.  It shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Because I need to write new html page when user visits xy.com page, and to write html with js I use `document.write`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you write directly to the page's DOM, be it with `document.write` or inserting a `<script>` element, is no longer considered to be a content script.

Instead, it executes outside of [the "isolated world"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) in the page's own context. That means it has no access to content script APIs or variables/functions defined in your content script.

You can still [communicate with page-level code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25838804/934239), though.

Comment: Maybe this is a new update "Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.": https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: @alayli No. What is meant is accessing extension data (options, etc.) without messaging.