# chrome.storage.sync call results in: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a textarea coded to run the save_notes function on blur. When save_notes invokes, I get this in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.save_notes
```

**Javascript code:**

```
var note_area = document.getElementById('notetext')

//// todo Create a function to save the textarea to local storage
// todo First check & load any previously saved notes

;(function load_notes() {
  if (note_area === "") {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("stored_obj", function(resultObj) {
      note_area.value = resultObj.stored_obj
    })
  }
})()

function save_notes () {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    stored_obj: note_area.value
  }, function () {
    // console.log("Saved into Chrome Storage")
  })
}

note_area.addEventListener('blur', save_notes)
```

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998123/chrome-storage-sync-undefined) the poster needed to add the storage permission to manifest.json.

My manifest.json has already included that line. I wonder if I'm missing some other necessary permission, or if there's an unrelated issue in the code itself.

**manifest.json**

```
  {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Mindless Blocker",
  "description": "Block mindless distractions and have a place to take notes for followup during free time",
  "version": "0.1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "cloud-icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change your manifest.json file, you have to reload your extensions list.

Go to [chrome://extensions/](http://chrome://extensions/) and press CTRL+R.