# chrome.storage.sync to save checkbox state --> error:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am struggling to save the state of a checkbox with the chrome.storage.sync
The Checkboxe should keep being checked/unchecked after page refresh.
My current code looks like this:

```html
<script>
function save(){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('option1');
    chrome.storage.sync.set('option1', checkbox.checked);
}

function load(){    
    var checked = JSON.parse( chrome.storage.sync.get('option1'));
    document.getElementById("option1").checked = checked;
}

load();

</script>
```

its not saving the state of the checkboxes and I always get the error:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined" even if I added the "storage" permission to my manifest.json

really need your help guys :D 
every suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chrome.storage.sync undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998123/chrome-storage-sync-undefined)

Comment: eddited the Thread @Andreas

Comment: the suggestions on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998123/chrome-storage-sync-undefined) didn't fix the problem

Comment: 1) You cannot use inline Javascript in a chrome extension. 2) You cannot access `chrome.storage` from a webpage. 3) Review the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage): `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous, it doesn't return a value, you have to use the callback function.

Comment: oh alright thank you @IvánNokonoko I thought I can use it from a webpage...

Comment: Use `localStorage` instead.